# How to get reference of '.fc-helper' from EventRender callback

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm developping a calendar application where I want to implement **travel time**.

I've edited `Grid.mixin eventsToNormalRanges: function(events)` (~line :4260)

where 
`eventStartMS: +eventStart` has been replaced with 
`eventStartMS: +eventStart.subtract(event.ttime, 'minutes')`

which made event duration longer by travel time. 
Then I've prepended eventRender element with travel-time div.

Now let's say, the **event starts at 2015-07-07 1:00AM** and has **2 hours travel-time.** 
Since the travel time is **2 hours** and we've made event duration longer,
the event will break in two events and show 
**1 hour at 2015-07-06**, now I need to **show the remaining hour** in the second event element.

Therefore I need to calculate **outerHeight** of first event element.
Theese classes may help us select the proper element `.fc-helper.fc-start.fc-not-end` and set correct height for `.fc-helper.fc-end.fc-not-start > div.travel-time` when traveling starts in different day.

However although the helper element seem to render simultaneously with event being rendered, it's not possible to get jQuery reference to helper element. (It is from developer console).

Here's my eventRender callback code.

```
function fullcalendar_event_render (event, element, view){
    $(element).addClass('calendar-event-'+event.id);
    if(view.name == "agendaWeek" || view.name == "agendaDay") {
      if(event.ttime > 0) {
        var row_height = $('.fc-minor').outerHeight(); //height of one half-hour slot
        var tt_size = event.ttime / 30; //how many slots would ttime take
        var height = row_height*tt_size-2; //total height of travel-time div

        if($(element).is('.fc-start.fc-end') || $(element).is('.fc-start.fc-not-end')){
           $(element).prepend('<div class="fc-travel-time" style="height:'+height+'px">Traveling: '+event.ttime+' Minutes</div>');
         }
        else if($(element).is('.fc-end.fc-not-start')) {
          var added = $('.calendar-event-'+event.id+'.fc-end.fc-not-start').find('.fc-travel-time').length; //check if we already added 'tt' div
          var start_height = $('.fc-start.fc-not-end.fc-helper').outerHeight();

          if(start_height && !added && start_height <= height) {
            $('.calendar-event-'+event.id+'.fc-end.fc-not-start').prepend('<div class="fc-travel-time" style="height:'+(height-start_height)+'px">Cesta: '+event.ttime+' Minut</div>');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

`start_height` is always **null** since we cant get reference to '.fc-helper' from inside of this function.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: The reason why im not playing with CSS in `eventAfterRender`, but the event itself may not be obvious. To clarify that, its because I need fullcalendar to handle eventOverlapping.